# Passing data to a modal in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

How can I pass data from a `browserWindow` to a `modal`?

I have the `openModal()` function in a renderer process, and I want to pass in data like `openModal(data)`.

How do you access the passed data in the modal?

```
function openModal(data) {

  let win = new remote.BrowserWindow({
    parent: remote.getCurrentWindow(),
      width: 600,
      height: 400
  });

  var theUrl = "file://" + __dirname + "/modal.html";

  win.setMenu(null); 
  win.loadURL(theUrl);
}

openModal(data);
```

Comment: You can use `ipcMain` and `ipcRenderer` but if you're only going to send the data once and it's not much data, I usually just attach it as a query string and then read the query string in JS

Comment: @dotconnor Thanks for the reply. How would the query string work? Is it appended on the `file://directory/modal.html?query=string` like so? And then read? How would it be read?